# onselect not calling function when a match is selected error Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-strap

I am trying to use bs-typeahead directive from angular-strap.

## * Update *

> http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/typeaheads

I want a fucntion to be executed when a user selects something from the options. But this simple case is not seems to be working here and throwing error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined

Here is my syntax:

## Template

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="selectedState" bs-options="state for state in states" bs-on-select="myFunction()" placeholder="Enter state" bs-typeahead>
```

## JS:

```
$scope.myFunction = function(){
  console.log("This function is called.")
  console.log($scope.selectedState);
}
```

Can anyone please help me here, if I am missing anything.

Here is my plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Z89TQ027WzxQn6UDJfAL?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your linked Plunker has no errors, but if you want the function to be called on every change, remove the wrapping parenthesis:

```
bs-on-select="myFunction"
```

Right now you're calling it in place, and assigning the return value of the function (which is nothing) as the `bs-on-select` handler.